# ListSerializer with Child 's PrimaryRelatedKeyField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When is_valid methods of ListSerializer, the queryset of the PrimaryRelatedKeyField of the Serializer specified as child is executed for the number of elements in the List. The queryset is evaluated as many times as the number of elements in the List. Is there any way to avoid this? I want to keep the number of SQL executions as low as possible.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    publisher = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Publisher.objects.all(), source="publisher")


class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = BookSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Book.objects.bulk_create([Book(**book) for book in validated_data])



books = [
    {'title': 'Django Basic', 'publisher': 1},
    {'title': 'Django Advance', 'publisher': 2},
    {'title': 'DRF Basic', 'publisher': 1},
    {'title': 'DRF Advance', 'publisher': 2},
    {'title': 'Django Professional', 'publisher': 2},
]
bookListSerializer = BookListSerializer(data=books)
# In validation, queryset ( Publisher.objects.all() ) is evaluated every times.
# In this example, it will be executed five times.
bookListSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
bookListSerializer.save()
```

If we define it as an IntegerField in the Serializer specified as child, it will not execute many querysets, but we have to validate in another part whether the correct id is specified or not.

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    publisher = serializers.IntegerField()


class BookListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = BookSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Book.objects.bulk_create([Book(**book) for book in validated_data])



books = [
    {'title': 'Django Basic', 'publisher': 1},
    {'title': 'Django Advance', 'publisher': 2},
    {'title': 'DRF Basic', 'publisher': 1},
    {'title': 'DRF Advance', 'publisher': 2},
    {'title': 'Django Professional', 'publisher': 2},
]

# Need a validation
book_id_list = [book['publisher'] for book in books]
if len(book_id_list) != Book.filter(id__in=book_id_list).count():
    raise serializers.ValidationError()

bookListSerializer = BookListSerializer(data=books)
bookListSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
bookListSerializer.save()
```